# How do I query Postgresql with IDs from a parquet file in an Data Factory pipeline

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-data-factory

I have an azure pipeline that moves data from one point to another in parquet files. I need to join some data from a Postgresql database that is in an AWS tenancy by a unique ID.  I am using a dataflow to create the unique ID I need from two separate columns using a concatenate.  I am trying to create where clause e.g.

```
select * from tablename where unique_id in ('id1','id2',id3'...)
```

I can do a lookup query to the database, but I can't figure out how to create the list of IDs in a parameter that I can use in the select statement out of the dataflow output.  I tried using a set variable and was going to put that into a for-each, but the set variable doesn't like the output of the dataflow (object instead of array).  "The variable 'xxx' of type 'Array' cannot be initialized or updated with value of type 'Object'. The variable 'xxx' only supports values of types 'Array'."  I've used a flatten to try to transform to array, but I think the sync operation is putting it back into JSON?

What a workable approach to getting the IDs into a string that I can put into a lookup query?

Some notes:
The parquet file has a small number of unique IDs compared to the total unique IDs in the database.
If this were an azure postgresql I could just use a join in the dataflow to do the join, but the generic postgresql driver isn't available in dataflows.  I can't copy the entire database over to Azure just to do the join and I need the dataflow in Azure for non-technical reasons.

Edit:
For clarity sake, I am trying to replace local python code that does the following:

```
query = "select * from mytable where id_number in "
df = pd.read_parquet("input_file.parquet")
df['id_number'] = df.country_code + df.id
df_other_data = pd.read_sql(conn, query + str(tuple(df.id_number))
```

I'd like to replace this locally executing code with ADF.  In the ADF process, I have to replace the transformation of the IDs which seems easy enough if a couple of different ways.  Once I have the IDs in the proper format in a column in a dataset, I can't figure out how to query a database that isn't supported by Data Flow and restrict it to only the IDs I need so I don't bring down the entire database.

Comment: Are your IDs from the output of a dataflow? Then you want store them into an Array type variable?

Comment: Can you show us some screenshots?

Comment: @JosephXu - Yes, I think so. My plan was to store the IDs in an Array type variable then do a for-each with a lookup into the database to get the data for each record. I might also be able to do a batch-style with a selection of the array elements like the existing SQL.  Open to other methods.

Comment: Maybe you can use an Array type parameter in pipeline to store Object type value.

Answer (score 1):

Due to variables of ADF only can store simple type. So we can define an Array type paramter in ADF and set default value. Paramters of ADF support any type of elements including complex JSON structure.
For example:

1. Define a json array:

```json
[{"name": "Steve","id": "001","tt_1": 0,"tt_2": 4,"tt3_": 1},{"name": "Tom","id": "002","tt_1": 10,"tt_2": 8,"tt3_": 1}]
```

2. Define an Array type paramter and set its default value:
   [image]

So we will not get any error.

Comment: How do I set the default value of of the JSON array with the values I create by joining columns in my input parquet file?  This approach looks promising.